# Двоеточие или тире?

Tags: двоеточие

"Афанасий напоминал медведя: огромный, заросший, неповоротливый" 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой знак нужно поставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень интересное предложение.
В Вашем примере нужно поставить двоеточие: ***"Афанасий напоминал медведя: огромный, заросший, неповоротливый"***  Это бессоюзное сложное предложение, второе - неполное, в нём опущены подлежащее и сказуемое "он был".  Второе предложение раскрывает содержание первого (или указывает на причину).
Но это же предложение можно записать по-другому: ***"Афанасий - огромный, заросший, неповоротливый - напоминал медведя."*** 
Здесь однородные обособленные определения относятся к имени собственному и стоят после него. Предложение простое, обособляем определения с помощью тире, так как между однородными членами уже стоят запятые.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой подробный ответ!